# Can not plot only the new values

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I am trying to make a plot (chart using oxyplot) that updates for every `timer.elapsed`. The plot I'm using is `OxyPlot`. The interval for timer is 500 ms and data gets collected in a `for loop` as following:

```
for (uint i = _startIndex; i < (_startIndex + _sampleCount); i++)
{
    SampleCont[i] = adc_to_mv(appBuffersPinned[0].Target[i], inputRanges[SelRangeIndex]);
    double power = SampleIntervalr * Math.Pow(10, -9);
    sampleTimeCont[i] = (double)(i * power);
}
```

Elapsed time and its methods to update the plot is according to following:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ss = "Timer elapsed" + Environment.NewLine;
    InsertText(ss);
    if (!sendit)
    {
       // if it's not a plot created plese initiate the plot first
       InitiateStreamPlot();
    }
    else
    {
        UpdatePlot();
    }
}
```

And then we have `InitiateStreamPlot`and `UpdatePlot` as following:

```
    private void InitiateStreamPlot()
    {
        myModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Voltage level" };
        ss = "New streaming plot is starting" + Environment.NewLine;

        series1 = new LineSeries
        {
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            MarkerSize = 1,
            Smooth = true,
            Title = "Voltage level",
            CanTrackerInterpolatePoints = false,

        };

        linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Title = "Time in nanosec" };
        linearAxis2 = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Title = "Voltage" };

        myModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
        myModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis2);

        for (int i = 0; i < SampleCont.Length; i++)
        {
            series1.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.DataPoint(sampleTimeCont[i], SampleCont[i]));
        }

        myModel.Series.Add(series1);
        plotView1.Model = myModel;
        sendit = true;
    }
```

And

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updating the chart.Invoke is required for not blocking UI thread
    /// since we use a timer we do calculations and reading in a other thread
    /// than UI thread.and for getting back those values and show them on UI
    /// thread invoking is required.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdatePlot()
    {

        if (plotView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            plotView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)UpdatePlot);
            //lbPoints.Invoke((MethodInvoker)UpdatePlot);

        }
        else
        {
            //while (series1.Points.Count > 0)
            //{

            //}
            if (series1.Points.Count > 0)
                series1.Points.Clear();

            if (myModel.Series.Count > 0)
                myModel.Series.Clear();


            string num = series1.Points.Count.ToString();
            lbPoints.Text = series1.Points.Count.ToString();
            //myModel.Series.Add(series1);

            for (int i = 0; i < SampleCont.Length; i++)
            {
                series1.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.DataPoint(sampleTimeCont[i], SampleCont[i]));
            }

            myModel.Series.Add(series1);

            //plotView1.Refresh();
            plotView1.InvalidatePlot(true);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the timer elapses there are some data collected in the for loop. and when the timer again is enable, the loop still collecting. That will result in new+old values in the `SampleCont` . so what I thing should be done instead is that I need to plot from `_startIndex` to `_sampleCount` first time. Next time there is a new value on `_sampleCount` ( it is a changing variable that says how many samples there are at the moment) . so I need to tell program that this time `_startIndex` should be equal to the old value of `_sampleCount` and `_sampleCount` should this time be `new` `_sampleCount` - `old` `_sampleCount`. and plot it. I don't really know how to tell the plot to do that. becouse `_sampleCount` get's update every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a generic list to store the old _sampleCount values.